python concurrent.futures.ThreadPool blocking
I have the code below.  read_sql is method on my DBReader class and it's using pd.read_sql.
Im parallelizing sql selects to the Postgres sql table.
import pandas as pd

def read_sql(self, sql, params = None):
  t1 = timeit.default_timer()
  with warnings.catch_warnings():
     warnings.simplefilter("ignore", UserWarning)
     with psycopg.connect(self.connect_str, autocommit=True) as conn:
        df = pd.read_sql(sql, con = conn, params = params)
     
     self.log.debug(f'perf: {timeit.default_timer() - t1}')
     return df

the concurrent futures code is this:
import concurrent.futures as cf

def test_thread_pool():
   db_reader = DataReader()
   sql = "select id, name from factor f where f.id = ANY(%s)"
   threads = 20
   id_partitions = np.array_split(list(range(1, 10000)), threads)
   id_partitions = [[p.tolist()] for p in id_partitions]
   with cf.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=threads) as exec:
      futures = {
         exec.submit(db_reader.read_sql, sql, params=p):
           p for p in id_partitions
      }
      
      for future in cf.as_completed(futures):
         ids = futures[future]
         try:
            df = future.result()
         except Exception as exc:
            log.exception(f'error retrieving data for: {ids}')
         else:
            if df is not None:
               print(f'shape: {df.shape}')   


The output of the debug line from read_sql looks like this:
perf: 0.7313497869981802
perf: 0.8116309550023288
perf: 3.401154975006648
perf: 5.22201336100261
perf: 6.325166654998611
perf: 6.338692951001576
perf: 6.573095380997984
perf: 6.5976604809984565
perf: 6.8282670119951945
perf: 7.291718505999597
perf: 7.4276196580030955
perf: 7.407097272000101
perf: 8.38801568299823
perf: 9.119963648998237

You'll notice that it is incrementing - id have expected it to be all roughly around the same time - so it seems there is some blocking somewhere.
Also, the time gap between the first two threads and 3rd is always about 2-3 seconds - why is that?
I've also tried creating a new DbReader instance for each thread..but same effect.
How do i solve this?

Remember that, in Python, only one thread can be running Python code at a time.  I don't know how much of pd.read_sql is Python code before it shifts to C, but if it has to do a lot of Python pre- and post-processing (which is possible), that will be a bottleneck.  You might consider pulling the SQL yourself before converting to a dataframe.

Yeah... interestingly it's still 2x faster than using a processing pool, even when going up to 40-50 threads and using longer running queries

I've had some issues with concurrent.futures too when working with pandas.DataFrame with heavy IO operations. Did you try reducing the number of threads or processes to the number of physical cores? (logical was still too much to handle for my computer but you could give it a try). For that specific case, I switched back to multiprocessing and had much better results with a reduced number of processes.

@antoine i feel that shouldnt be necessary for non-process or non-cpu bound operations. am i mistaken?  that said, i am limiting number of threads to 20 and same when i try the multprocessing (as i think you can be a bit more liberal for non cpu bound operations with multiprocessing as well)

I agree with you. In my case, I was reading large NetCDF files (over 1GB) and it turned out I was limited by RAM. So decreasing the number of processes/cores did not slow the whole process, CPU usage was still 100%, but it freed some RAM and avoided using swap.

Is this really the SQL of your actual query? If so and if id is an integer column, then all of the desired rows can be retrieved with sql = "select id, name from factor f where f.id between 1 and 99999" using a single thread.

@Booboo its specifically for testing multithreading...the real query is a bit more complex with some joins
